# Combine, count df columns w/o repeating other columns

Tags: r, merge, bind, reshape

A simple question that I am completely stumped on after consulting packages thatI thought would help(plyr, reshape, unique)

Let's say I have the df below:

```
df <- data.frame(location=c("ny","nj","pa","ct"),
                 animal=c("dog","hamster","dog","pig"),
                 animal2=c("cat","dog","pig","dog"))
```

I would like to count the unique entities in specific columns and then rank occurrences. So here, I'd like to count the combined unique entities in the columns animal and animal2. If I use reshape and melt, the associated location values will repeat in the additional rows...but I don't want that because I only want to count the frequencies of the "location' variables as given in the original df.

Is there a way to rbind without repeating other columns? So in this case I would have another column called AnimalMaster and that would have all of the frequencies I need.

When I try `count(df,c("animal","animal2"))`, it counts the joint occurrences, which is not what I want. Alternatively, I could also do this by just counting the unique strings across multiple columns without combining them. Is there a straightforward way to do this without running into the count problem?

Thank you for helping a beginner.

#### EDIT:

My desired output is the following:

`countsdf` with columns (Type, Name, Frequency, Frequency (%)), so that top row would be:

```
AnimalMaster | dog | 4 | 100%
```

Comment: Can you please add the desired output. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, of course. Added it in original.

Comment: Where does "AnimalMaster" come from?

Comment: That would be if there was a way to add a column that combined all of the elements in animal and animal2 columns, while not repeating the entries in the location column

Answer (score 2):

Here's a suggestion with `reshape2` and `data.table`

```
require(reshape2)
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(melt(df, id.vars = 'location', value.name = 'animal'))
dt[, list(n=length(unique(location)), 
          percent=100*.N/dt[, length(unique(location))]), 
   by=animal]
#      animal n percent
#  1:     dog 4     100
#  2: hamster 1      25
#  3:     pig 2      50
#  4:     cat 1      25
```